# `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),` Error in python snippet in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running the following python snippet on my data(1500x2 matrix), and trying to implement KMeans algorithm from scratch:-

```
def closestCentroids(arr, centroids):
idx = np.zeros(arr.shape[0]);
for i in range(0, arr.shape[0]):
    idx[i] = 0
    for j in range(0, centroids.shape[0]):
        if(np.linalg.norm(arr[i]-centroids[j]) < np.linalg.norm(arr[i]-centroids[idx[i]])):
            idx[i] = j
return idx

def computeCentroids(arr, idx, k = 3):
    centroids = np.zeros((k, arr.shape[1]))

    for i in range(0, k):
        idx_k = (idx==i).sum()
        centroids[i] = (arr[np.where(idx == i)].sum(axis=0))/idx_k
    return centroids

def kMeans(arr, k = 3):
    centroids = arr[np.random.randint(arr.shape[0], size = k), :]
    idx = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])
    for i in range(0, 50):
        idx = closestCentroids(arr, centroids)
        centroids = computeCentroids(arr, idx, k=3)
    return centroids
```

The error occurs at line `if(np.linalg.norm(arr[i]-centroids[j]) < np.linalg.norm(arr[i]-centroids[idx[i]])):` when i'm comparing the eucidean distance of the points. I don't know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `numpy.zeros()` creates an array of floating point values, so your array `idx` is a floating point array.  You use the values of `idx` to index the array `centroids`, and numpy doesn't allow indexing with floating point values, so `idx` must be an integer array.

Change the creation of `idx` to

```
idx = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], dtype=int)
```